# ADO.NET Entity Data Model (Entity object)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, ado.net

I have entity instance(north)

```
NorthdatabaseEntity north = new NorthdatabaseEntity()
```

The problem is that i don't have access to ObjectContext methods. I tried to call them with object "north" but i didn't found the method "AddObject" or any other from ObjectContext.
I thought that any entity object has all methods from ObjectContext class.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: Only the context object is responsible for managing entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectContext and entities are different objects; you may use `ObjectContext` to add/modify/delete objects, but entities does not have direct access to `ObjectContext`.

You need to create an instance of `ObjectContext` and perform your operations on itself, not on entities.

Comment: I have example in VS2012 with following code static int SelectCustomersCount()
  {
    NorthwindEntities northwindEntities = new NorthwindEntities();
    string nativeSQLQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.Customers";
    var queryResult = northwindEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(nativeSQLQuery);
    int customersCount = queryResult.FirstOrDefault();
    return customersCount;
  } and here it works but when I try to create my own object i cannot see the method "ExecuteStoreQuery()" or "AddObject()" method with my entity object. Why in this example work ?

Comment: But why NorthwindEntities object in the example can see methods like "ExecuteStoreQuery()", "AddObject()" and my object cannot ? They are from the same type (NorthwindEntities).

Comment: can you put the cursor on NorthdatabaseEntity and press F12. What is the base type of NorthdatabaseEntity?

Comment: When I pressed F12 I saw that the class "NorthwindEntities" from the example is "public partial class NorthwindEntities : ObjectContext".
My object is from the same class "NorthwindEntities" but whe n I press   F12 I saw "public partial class NorthwindEntities : DbContext". Why when I create my own object the class inherit DBContext, the other from example inherit ObjectContext. This is the  problem i think but why VS make them inherit from different classes ?

Comment: Yes.But I think the problem here is that my class inherit DBContext and with F12 i changed from "DBContext" to "ObjectContext" and now it work as i want to work. But is it a good practice to change the classes structure with F12 ? What do you think ?

Comment: the problem here is that: you are using EF5; but the sample code employs EF4; EF5 employs DBContext, EF4 employs ObjectContext. In fact DBContext is just an abstraction of ObjectContext. refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Now I understand. How can I change EF from 5 to 4 and how can I see what EF I am using right now ?

Comment: you need to reference the EF4 dll in the project instead of EF5 dll.; in the project references right click on the EF dll and select properties, it shows the version of the dll used..